# google map, show tooltip on a circle

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, tooltip

I know I can make a marker with a tooltip that shows "SOMETHING" like this:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        title:"SOMETHING",
        icon: '/public/markers-map/male-2.png'
    });
```

I want to do the same with a circle but **title** doesn't work.

```
new google.maps.Circle({
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
                radius: 20,
                strokeColor: "blue",
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                title:"SOMETHING",
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: "blue",
                fillOpacity: 1,
                map: map
            });
```

It prints the circle but does not show the message "SOMETHING".

How can I do it? is there another property to get it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The tooltip is created via the native `title`-attribute of DOM-elements, but the API doesn't provide any method to access the DOMElement that contains the circle.

A possible workaround may be to use the title-attribute of the map-div instead(set it `onmouseover` and remove it `onmouseout`)

```
        //circle is the google.maps.Circle-instance
        google.maps.event.addListener(circle,'mouseover',function(){
             this.getMap().getDiv().setAttribute('title',this.get('title'));});

        google.maps.event.addListener(circle,'mouseout',function(){
             this.getMap().getDiv().removeAttribute('title');});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use InfoWindow instead of html title attribute, as the title may not show up always on mouse over. InfoWindow looks pretty good.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
});
```

Then use same mouseover event mechanism to show the InfoWindow:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'mouseover', function () {
 if (typeof this.title !== "undefined") {
    marker.setPosition(this.getCenter()); // get circle's center
    infowindow.setContent("<b>" + this.title + "</b>"); // set content
    infowindow.open(map, marker); // open at marker's location
    marker.setVisible(false); // hide the marker
   }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'mouseout', function () {
 infowindow.close();
});
```

Comment: Also have a look at https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window#examples

Answer (score 3):

> Also we can add event listener direct on google.maps.Circle instance.

Code sample:

```
//circle is the google.maps.Circle-instance
circle.addListener('mouseover',function(){
    this.getMap().getDiv().setAttribute('title',this.get('title'));
});

circle.addListener('mouseout',function(){
    this.getMap().getDiv().removeAttribute('title');
});
```

Just wrote for alternative!